# submit values using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, submit

.I have this code1:

```
<form method="GET" action="picture.php">
```

.usually the value of i1 will be sent if i use this code2:

```
<input type="submit">
```

.Is there a way to trigger the "submit" function by using a jquery instead of code2? help pls!

Comment: Please, add the tags "jquery" and "javascript" next time. Thanks.

Comment: Alright.. i'm sorry for that.

Comment: Please include the full HTML of the form you are using.

Answer (score 2):

```
<form method="GET" action="picture.php" id="picture-form">
```

... followed by the following call in javascript, wherever it might be required ...

```
$('form#picture-form').submit();
```

Note that an ID has been added to the form for an accurate jQuery reference.  just doing `$('form').submit();` could be very evil.

Fully fledged example follows.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="GET" action="picture.php" id="picture-form">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="$('form#picture-form').submit();">Submit me!</a>
</form>
```

Comment: +1.. btw i wouln't use "followed by", he might actually get it literally.

Comment: .I used your code $('form#picture-form').submit(); but still when i click the link is does not forward the code to the next php page.

Comment: It definitely can work.  I've knocked up a really simple example above.  If you can post what you've got, maybe we can spot why it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this link : http://api.jquery.com/submit/ -
*Bind an event handler to the "submit" JavaScript event, or trigger that event on an element.*

Answer (score 0):

There's even no need for jQuery, you can do it in *vanilla* JavaScript:

```
<form method="GET" action="picture.php" id="picture-form">
 <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById("picture-form").submit()>Click me!</a>
... 
</form>
```